# Django and Suds : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'str' in suds

Tags: django, suds

I have a little problem using Suds in Django (1.3, python 2.7).

When I retrieve data using suds in a script, it works ;
but if I put the ** exactyle same** code in a django view, I get the error :

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'str' in suds
```

My code is simple :

```
client = Client(WSDL_URL, location=LOCATION_URL, cache=None)
client.service.getRooms({'type':'AVAILABLE'})
```

And the complete traceback :

```
File "/Users/lundi/Irusia/WWW/rooms/views.py", line 45, in available
    client.service.getRooms({'type':'AVAILABLE'})
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/client.py", line 595, in invoke
    soapenv = binding.get_message(self.method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 120, in get_message
    content = self.bodycontent(method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/bindings/document.py", line 63, in bodycontent
    p = self.mkparam(method, pd, value)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/bindings/document.py", line 105, in mkparam
    return Binding.mkparam(self, method, pdef, object)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 287, in mkparam
    return marshaller.process(content)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/mx/core.py", line 62, in process
    self.append(document, content)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/mx/core.py", line 73, in append
    log.debug('appending parent:\n%s\ncontent:\n%s', parent, content)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1120, in debug
    self._log(DEBUG, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1250, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1260, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1300, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 744, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 791, in emit
    msg = self.format(record) + '\000'
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 719, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/Users/lundi/Irusia/WWW/base/log.py", line 22, in format
    s = '%s [%s] %s: %s' % (dt, record.name, record.levelname, record.getMessage())
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 328, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/sax/document.py", line 58, in __str__
    return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/sax/document.py", line 61, in __unicode__
    return self.str()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/sax/document.py", line 48, in str
    s.append(self.root().str())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I don't know why I get this error using Django.

I thinks it's the same problem that this person : [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'str' in suds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644520/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-str-in-suds)

So if anyone has an idea,

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:

`s = '%s [%s] %s: %s' % (dt, record.name, record.levelname, record.getMessage())`

One of these variables is `None`, my initial suspect is `dt`.

Answer (score 12):

The bug is in suds but is normally silent. However the bug is exposed when using django-debug-toolbar, as the logging panel shows all the messages that have been logged.

I've created a patched version of suds that fixes this problem: https://github.com/bradleyayers/suds-htj